# How to connect to MinIO bucket with argo workflow?

Tags: argo-workflows, argo

I am trying to connect to my MinIO bucket from an argo workflow. However, my pod fails to initialise with the following error:

> MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "argo-artifacts" : secret "argo-artifacts" not found<

But if i run:

> kubectl get secrets

It does list argo-artifacts

How can i make my workflow run succesfully connected to the bucket.
(This is what I am trying to get working: https://argoproj.github.io/argo-workflows/walk-through/artifacts/)

Answer (score 0):

It was because the secret was in a different namespace. Creating the secret in the same namespace as the pods did resolve the issue.